# custom Adapter not working properly after filter applied in android

Tags: android, adapter, autocompletetextview

[image: There is adapter set to Station(Name/Code) AutocompleteTextView]

There is adapter set to Station(Name/Code) AutocompleteTextView. First time whole list is setting. After that If I filter for `ch`, It will display all filtered Items.

And Now If i remove `ch`, It will display whole list. Here there is no problem.

But Now If click back button or navigate tot other screen and coming to this screen again, there is only filtered Items are displaying(which are starts with ch).

Why only filtered Items are showing?

Please help me.

This is very important for my project.

I tried many solutions on google. But not got the output.

Any help would be appreciated.

> This is my custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private final Context mContext;
private ArrayList<TextItem> textObjects;
private ArrayList<TextItem> textObjects_All;
private final int mLayoutResourceId;
View rowView;
private  LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<TextItem> AObjects) {
    super(mContext, resource, AObjects);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mLayoutResourceId = resource;

    setTextObjects(AObjects);
}

public void setTextObjects(ArrayList<TextItem> AObjects) {
    try {
        textObjects = AObjects;
        textObjects_All = new ArrayList<>();
        synchronized (this) {
            textObjects_All.addAll(AObjects);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("eEmp/setTextObj", "Expt due to " + e.toString());
    }

}

public int getCount() {
    return textObjects.size();
}

public TextItem getItem(int position) {
   return textObjects.get(position);
    //return (textObjects != null ? textObjects.get(position) : "");
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public void addTextObject(TextItem newItem) {
    try {
        if ((textObjects_All != null) && (!textObjects_All.contains(newItem))) {
            textObjects_All.add(newItem);
        }
    } catch (Exception expt) {
        Log.d("eEmp/setTextObj", "Expt due to " + expt.toString());
    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null){
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        TextItem selectedItem = (TextItem) getItem(position);
        TextView txtHeaderObject = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderItem);
        txtHeaderObject.setText(selectedItem.headItemName);

        TextView txtSubItem1Object = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSub1Item);
        if (txtSubItem1Object != null) {
            txtSubItem1Object.setText(selectedItem.subItem1Name);
        }

        TextView txtSubItem2Object = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSub2Item);
        if (txtSubItem2Object != null) {
            txtSubItem2Object.setText(selectedItem.subItem2Name);
        }


        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = rowView.getLayoutParams();

        return rowView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("/eEmp","/Convert View Exception"+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rowView;

}
private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView Header;
    TextView SubItem1;
    TextView SubItem2;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {


    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return ((TextItem) resultValue).headItemName;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            try {
                if ((constraint == null) || (constraint.length() == 0)) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        filterResults.values = textObjects_All;
                        filterResults.count = textObjects_All.size();
                    }
                } else {
                    ArrayList<TextItem> textObjectsFiltered = new ArrayList<TextItem>();
                    for (TextItem obj : textObjects_All) {
                        TextItem itemObj = obj;

                        if (itemObj != null) {
                            if ((itemObj.headItemName != null) && (itemObj.headItemName.length() != 0)
                                    && (itemObj.headItemName.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))) {
                                textObjectsFiltered.add(obj);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.values = textObjectsFiltered;
                    filterResults.count = textObjectsFiltered.size();
                }
            } catch (Exception expt) {
                Log.d("eEmp/FilterResults", "Exception Occurred due to " + expt.toString());
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("SingleStatementInBlock")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            try{
                textObjects.clear();
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    ArrayList<?> result = (ArrayList<?>) results.values;
                    for (Object object : result) {
                        if (object instanceof TextItem) {
                            textObjects.add((TextItem) object);
                        }
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }catch (Exception expt) {
                Log.d("eEmp/publishResults", "Exception Occurred due to " + expt.toString());
            }

        }
    };
}
}
```

> AutoCompleteTextWatcher.java

```
public class AutoCompleteTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private CustomAutoCompleteTextView currATV;

public AutoCompleteTextWatcher(CustomAutoCompleteTextView tv)
{
    currATV = tv;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(currATV != null)
    {
        currATV.setTextItemTag(null);
    }
}
}
```

atcvDivName is my AutoCompleteTextView

> Activity

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_fab_activity, container, false);
    try {


        Inst_Act_List_works_entry = new ArrayList<>();//added by pavani


        status_pojo = new Status_POJO();
        edtFromDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtFromDate);
        edtFromDate.setText(getTodayDates()); // Added in V 1.3 by Shamili
        // Get Available WorkTypes
        WorkTypes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WorkTypes)));


        actvDivName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher());
        //set event for clear button
        btnClear_stn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());

        actvEntryCategory.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher_Entry());
        btn_clear_EntryType.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());

        btn_clear_Product.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
        actvPType.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher_Product());

        cd_leaves.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (stn_fal_falg == 1) {
            btnClear_stn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_clear_EntryType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn_clear_Product.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            btnClear_stn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_clear_EntryType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_clear_Product.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        try {
            WorksList = dbHandler.getWorkTypes();
            for (String newWorkType : WorksList) {
                if (!WorkTypes.contains(newWorkType)) {
                    WorkTypes.add(newWorkType);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception getWorkExp) {

        }

        EntryTypeAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.autocomplete_text_layout, WorkTypes);
        actvEntryCategory.setAdapter(EntryTypeAdapter);
        actvEntryCategory.setThreshold(0);

        Rlys = new ArrayList<Rly>();

        try {
            DivStnList = mContext.StnsPlacesList;
            for (int i = 0; i < DivStnList.size(); i++) {
                QRDivTextItemList = mContext.StnsPlacesList;
                DivIDsList.add(DivStnList.get(i).did);
                StnIDsList.add(DivStnList.get(i).id);
                DivList.add(DivStnList.get(i).subItem2Name);
                StnsList.add(DivStnList.get(i).headItemName);
            }
        } catch (Exception getDivExp) {

        }

        actvDivName.setThreshold(0);
        actvDivName.addTextChangedListener(new AutoCompleteTextWatcher(actvDivName));
        actvDivName.setOnItemClickListener(new AutoCompleteItemClickListener<TextItem>(QRDivTextItemList, actvDivName));
        QRDivArrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, R.layout.autocomplete_text_view, QRDivTextItemList);
        actvDivName.setAdapter(QRDivArrayAdapter);

        actvDivName.setCustomAutoCompleteTextViewListener(new CustomAutoCompleteTextView.CustomAutoCompleteTextViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected() {
                try {
                    TextItem selectedItem = (TextItem) actvDivName.getTag();
                    InstRecyclerclear();
                    FailureRecyclerclear();
                    GeneralRecyclerclear();
                    actvPType.setText("");
                    ProdsItemList.clear();
                    actvDivName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    actvPType.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cdAmc_entry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    trAMC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (selectedItem != null) {
                        instProd = (List<InstProd>) selectedItem.childObject;
                        for (int i = 0; i < instProd.size(); i++) {
                            TextItem item = new TextItem();
                            stn_pla_id = selectedItem.id;
                            item.headItemName = instProd.get(i).IName;
                            item.subItem1Name = instProd.get(i).MName;//String.valueOf(instProd.get(i).PID);
                            item.subItem2Name = instProd.get(i).NAME;//String.valueOf(instProd.get(i).IID);
                            item.id = instProd.get(i).PID;
                            item.did = instProd.get(i).IID;
                            prod_ID = instProd.get(i).PID;
                            ProdsItemList.add(item);
                            actvPType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            actvPType.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                    QRProdArrayAdapter.setTextObjects(ProdsItemList);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });
        QRProdArrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, R.layout.autocomplete_text_view, ProdsItemList);//added by pavani
        actvPType.setAdapter(QRProdArrayAdapter);//added by pavani

        actvPType.setThreshold(0);
        actvPType.addTextChangedListener(new AutoCompleteTextWatcher(actvPType));

        actvPType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    InstRecyclerclear();
                    FailureRecyclerclear();
                    GeneralRecyclerclear();
                    cdAmc_entry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    trAMC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    val = position;
                    iid = ProdsItemList.get(position).did;//Integer.parseInt(ProdsItemList.get(position).subItem2Name);
                    pid = ProdsItemList.get(position).id;//Integer.parseInt(ProdsItemList.get(position).subItem1Name);
                    station = ProdsItemList.get(position).headItemName;
                    product = ProdsItemList.get(position).subItem1Name;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("eEmp/OnProdClick", "Exception Occurred due to " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }); 

        actvDivName.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        entryFragment = (Entry_Fragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(EmpConstants.Entry_Info_Tag);


        //set Station Name
        if (StnIDFromAdapter != null) {

            try {
                long id = Long.parseLong(StnIDFromAdapter);
                stn_pla_id = id;
                for (int i = 0; i < DivStnList.size(); i++) {
                    if (id == DivStnList.get(i).id) {

                        actvDivName.setText(DivStnList.get(i).headItemName);
                        actvDivName.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception expt) {

            }
        }
        //setting Product Name
        if (ProdFromAdapter != null) {

            try {
                pid = ProdIdFromAdapter;
                iid = ProdSno;
                actvPType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                actvPType.setText(ProdFromAdapter);
                actvPType.setEnabled(false);
            } catch (Exception expt) {

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception expt) {
        Log.d("eEmp/EntryCreate", "Exception Occurred due to " + expt.toString());
    }

    return rootView;
}

private TextWatcher textWatcher() {
    return new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                if (!actvDivName.getText().toString().equals("")) { 
                    btnClear_stn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else { 

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Share your activity code, also make sure that you are not setting default filter for hardcoded text "ch"

Comment: I updated code. Please check And I am not hardcoded @KrishnaSharma

Comment: I think you also need to share the code for AutoCompleteTextWatcher , what is actvDivName ?

Comment: I added AutoCompleteTextWatcher.please check once sir@KrishnaSharma

Comment: please share the activity class as well if possible, that will help to find out the root cause.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma Activity Code added in the question please check sir

Comment: Activity code is incomplete, hard to understand with just few lines of code. please share complete activity class

Comment: I am interested to know the code where you calling `adapter.getFilter().filter(<search_criteria>);`

Comment: @KrishnaSharma Please check getFilter()  method in custom Adapter sir

Comment: Share the activity class please then only we can find out the cause